# YQL - What is syntax to query data for the past 3 months in YQL?

Tags: sql, yql, yahoo-api, yahoo-finance

I have this query and I want to change it so that it gets data for the past 3 months (or 90 days from now).

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "YHOO" and startDate = "2009-09-11" and endDate = "2010-03-10"
```

Is there any "lookback" function available in YQL?

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: Hi @WhoAmI thanks for replying,  the issue is I want to modify my query so that it qualifies data for  the past 3 months (example get historical data 3 months from now).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. where are you using the YQL query? I mean, are you using it in like jQuery or python or php?

Comment: Hi @WhoAmI Im using it for Android

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use YQL, I would suggest playing around with the YQL developer console (with community tables enabled)

Here: https://developer.yahoo.com/yql/console/?q=show%20tables&env=store://datatables.org/alltableswithkeys

The following YQL statement would get the historical data for Yahoo from the start of the year to yesterday:

```
select * from yahoo.finance.historicaldata where symbol = "YHOO" and startDate = "2016-01-01" and endDate = "2016-03-24"
```

This URL will generate the following JSON response:

```
https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20yahoo.finance.historicaldata%20where%20symbol%20%3D%20%22YHOO%22%20and%20startDate%20%3D%20%222016-01-01%22%20and%20endDate%20%3D%20%222016-03-24%22&format=json&diagnostics=true&env=store%3A%2F%2Fdatatables.org%2Falltableswithkeys&callback=
```